# NodeJS 4.4 increase allocated memory

Tags: node.js, memory, out-of-memory, win64

my server fails when ~1,5Gb RAM is allocated.
I am trying to allow it to allocate more this way:

```
...
var v = require('v8');

console.log('statistics: \n', v.getHeapStatistics());

v.setFlagsFromString('--max_old_space_size=8192');
v.setFlagsFromString('--max-new-space-size=8192');

console.log('statistics: ', v.getHeapStatistics());
...
```

this is the console output:

```
statistics: 
 { total_heap_size: 56906064,
  total_heap_size_executable: 8388608,
  total_physical_size: 56906064,
  total_available_size: 4112338936,
  used_heap_size: 24765096,
  heap_size_limit: 4160749568 }
statistics:  { total_heap_size: 56906064,
  total_heap_size_executable: 8388608,
  total_physical_size: 56906064,
  total_available_size: 4111227648,
  used_heap_size: 25487616,
  heap_size_limit: 4160749568 }
```

so you see, it's doing basically nothing and server fails with the same conditions.

Have tried to set the flags on the command line:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --max-old-space-size=8192 run.js
```

but it's the same.

Running Win7x64

Can you help out? I need at least 8 gigs..

Comment: Are you running `node` executable compiled for x64 architecture?

Comment: yes, node-v4.4.2-x64

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you running into a Node.js memory limit and not one of the [Windows memory limits for processes?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx#memory_limits). Several of those are 2 GB.

Perhaps what appears to be 1.5 GB is actually an indication of one those 2 GB limits.  From the linked page, a workaround is not listed.

Comment: well.. I'm not sure but I wouldn't say so. I can remember that I was running process which filled 8 gigs of the memory on this system

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. I fixed it by using "increase-memory-limit" npm package. All you would need is to run these 2 commands:

`npm install increase-memory-limit
increase-memory-limit`